# Отступ для всех блоков, кроме первого или последнего

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Приветствую!

К примеру: есть список с четырьмя элементами

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
<ul>
```

между которыми нужно сделать отступ по высоте, так, чтобы при `li { margin-top; }` первый элемент списка не сдвигался вниз от края родителя.
Если проще: нужно чтобы для первого li, margin-top не срабатывал.

Тоже самое справедливо и для `margin-bottom`, только в этом случаи - отступа не должно быть после последнего элемента.

Понятно что сдвигаемому элементу можно назначить признак(например дать класс) и уже по нему назначить `margin`, но неужели в CSS нет отдельного свойства для этого?

Comment: `li:first-child`, `li:last-child`

Comment: li:first-child ~ li{margin-top:10px}

Answer (score 7):

Может так что-то можно сварганить?

```css
ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  background: red;
  
  /*
      тут блок свойств общих для всех li
      кроме первого и последнего
  */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

[:first-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child) - применяет стилевое оформление к первому дочернему элементу своего родителя.

[:last-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child) - задает стилевое оформление последнего элемента своего родителя.

[:not](http://htmlbook.ru/css/not) -  задаёт правила стилей для элементов, которые **не содержат** указанный селектор.

Answer (score 1):

Такое решение:

```
ul > * + * {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `li:first-child`, `li:last-child`.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Code */

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
<ul>
```

Однако если есть скрытые элементы, как например в примере выше, из-за чего не применяется `li:last-child`, то можно использовать `li:first-of-type` и `li:last-of-type`.

```css
ul{
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 0;
}
ul ul{
   display: none;
}

li{
  border: 1px solid red;
  list-style: none;
}

/* Code */
li{
   margin: 10px 0;
}

li:first-of-type{
  margin-top: 0;
}
li:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
<ul>
```